# Neo4j - java Authentication failure

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I'm a beginner for Java and neo4j.
Trying my first connection to neo4j using Java Application. I'm unable to understand why I am getting Error:
`Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.AuthenticationException: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.`

- Bolt : bolt://localhost:7687 (neo4j Desktop on my macbook)
- GraphName : PrakashTest1
- Password : 12345678

Java Application:

```
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.AuthTokens;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Driver;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Session;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.StatementResult;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.driver.v1.TransactionWork;

import static org.neo4j.driver.v1.Values.parameters;

public class HelloWorldExample implements AutoCloseable {

  private final Driver driver;

  public HelloWorldExample( String uri, String user, String password ) 
  {
      driver = GraphDatabase.driver( uri, AuthTokens.basic( user, password ) );
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws Exception 
  {
      driver.close();
  }

  public void printGreeting( final String message ) {
      try ( Session session = driver.session() )
      {
          String greeting = session.writeTransaction( new TransactionWork<String>()
          {
              @Override
              public String execute( Transaction tx )
              {
                  StatementResult result = tx.run( "CREATE (a:Greeting) " +
                                                    "SET a.message = $message " +
                                                    "RETURN a.message + ', from node ' + id(a)",
                          parameters( "message", message ) );
                  return result.single().get( 0 ).asString();
              }
          } );
          System.out.println( greeting );
      }
  }

  public static void main( String... args ) throws Exception
  {
      try ( HelloWorldExample greeter = new HelloWorldExample( "bolt://localhost:7687", "PrakashTest1", "12345678" ) )
      {
          greeter.printGreeting( "hello, world" );
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: From what I understand you are using the user `PrakashTest1` , but it should be `neo4j`.

Comment: @logisima Your suggestion worked.

Comment: Authentication is successful but my java code might have a problem, it is not creating the desired result ie. not creating the nodes in neo4j and nothing in return.